# Svg image inside colored <div>: how to apply mix-blend-mode to the HTML background color?

Tags: html, svg, mix-blend-mode

I have a SVG file with `mix-blend-mode` styles defined on specific elements. The blend applies correctly to the other elements inside the SVG, but not to the containing HTML `<div>` background color.

Example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
        main {
            height: 100px;
            background-color: darkred;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="180" height="180" viewBox="0 0 450 450">
            <circle cx="174" cy="165" r="160" style="fill: yellow" />
            <circle  cx="245" cy="260" r="160" style="mix-blend-mode: multiply; fill: darkcyan" />
        </svg>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I improve it, so that the darkcyan color alters the red HTML background ?

[image: Screenshot]

Wanted result:

[image: Wanted result]

Answer (score 0):

Add a `mix-blend-mode` rule to the `<svg>`?  Is this what you are after?

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
main {
   height: 100px;
   background-color: darkred;
}
svg {
   mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="180" height="180" viewBox="0 0 450 450">
        <circle cx="174" cy="165" r="160" style="fill: yellow" />
        <circle  cx="245" cy="260" r="160" style="mix-blend-mode: multiply; fill: darkcyan" />
    </svg>
</main>
```

Comment: No: a part of the image must be in plain colors (here, the yellow circle), while the other part must blend with everything behind it, including the HTML background. I updated my question with the wanted result.

Comment: Are you using Firefox?  I get the result you are after just with your original SVG on Chrome.  But it doesn't work on Firefox. I am not sure why.

Comment: Indeed. I will look for issues about it on firefox, thank you.